# Subview randomly changes location by 40 pixels?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, constraints

I have a subview that covers the full screen of the iphone 5, and whenever I build and run all of a sudden its frame is (0,-40,320,586) instead of (0,0,320,586). So it like moves up for some reason. Right now I unchecked 'use autolayout' in the file inspector. This gets rid of all those annoying constraint thingies which I don't understand what they do.

Whenever I check 'use autolayout' enabling the constraints I notice this fixes the problem, and the subview doesn't randomly move up 40 pixels.

However, I can't keep these constraints on because I do animations with the subview, which don't work whenever the constraints are enabled.

What can I do?

Comment: i have some code in viewwillappear would that cause any problems, but none of it involves the subview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use autolayout at any point [read and learn about the autolayout system and constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html). If you don't want to, turn it off and don't use it.

In your case, if you want to get rid of it for a single view, perhaps it is enough to remove all constraints from that view. That can be done like this:
`[view removeConstraints:view.constraints]`.

[Autolayout reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html).